# Use output as an variable for use in devops yml definition

Tags: variables, azure-devops, terraform, yaml, azure-pipelines

Im trying to create variables for the output shown below so i can use it in a buildefinition yml.

I can get the SPN appID and storage access key manually but i want to get it automatically as a part of the terraform setup.

Using variables like this wont work as i cant hardcode the value in the default definition. Is there any other way to do this?

```
variable "client_id" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  description = "description"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**OUTPUT**

```
output "appid_tfazsp" {
  value     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
  sensitive = true
}
```

```
output "pass_tfazsp" {
  value     = azuread_service_principal_password.tfazsp.value
  sensitive = true
}
```

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "SASPass" {
  name                = var.storageAccount_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_name.name
}

output "storage_account_SASPass" {
  value     = data.azurerm_storage_account.stg.primary_access_key
  sensitive = true
}
```

**BuildDefinition**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

  paths:
    include:
      - /Azure-Terraform/variables.tf
      - /Azure-Terraform/main.tf
        /Azure-Terraform/ado_variables.tf


pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

variables:
  - group: hawaVB
  - name: state_file
    value: tf-statefile.state

steps:
  - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
    displayName: 'Install Terraform'
  - script: terraform version
    displayName: Terraform Version
  - script:  az login --service-principal -u $(application_id) -p $(SPNPass) --tenant $(tenant_id)
    displayName: 'Log Into Azure'
  - script: terraform init -backend-config=resource_group_name=$(rg_name) -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(storageAccount_name)" -backend-config="container_name=$(cont_name)" -backend-config="access_key=$(SASPass)" -backend-config="key=$(state_file)"
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Azure-Terraform
  - script: terraform plan -var="client_id=$(application_id)" -var="SPNPass=$(SPNPass)" -var="tenant_id=$(tenant_id)" -var="subscription_id=$(subscription_id)" -var="VmAdminPass=$(VmAdminPass)" -out="out.plan"
    displayName: Terraform Plan
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Azure-Terraform
  - script: terraform apply out.plan
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Azure-Terraform
```

Tried various ways of setting up the code to use it as a variable but no go

Updated pipeline:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

  paths:
    include:
      - /TFAZ/variables.tf
      - /TFAZ/main.tf

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  - group: hawaVB
  
steps:
  - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
    displayName: 'Install Terraform'
  - script: terraform version
    displayName: Terraform Version
  - task: PowerShell@1
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storage_account_SASPass;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -raw outputvar)"
        
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pass_tfazsp;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -raw outputvar)"
        
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appid_tfazsp;isOutput=true]$(terraform output -raw outputvar)"
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFAZ

  - script: az login --service-principal -u $(appid_tfazsp) -p $(pass_tfazsp) --tenant $(tenant_id)
    displayName: 'Log Into Azure'
  - script: terraform init -backend-config=resource_group_name=$(rg_name) -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(storageAccount_name)" -backend-config="container_name=$(cont_name)" -backend-config="access_key=$(storage_account_SASPass)" -backend-config="key=$(state_file)"
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFAZ
  - script: terraform plan -var=$(appid_tfazsp) -var="$(pass_tfazsp)" -var="tenant_id=$(tenant_id)" -var="subscription_id=$(subscription_id)" -var=$(VMAdminPass) -out="out.plan"
    displayName: Terraform Plan
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFAZ
  - script: terraform apply out.plan
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFAZ
```

Comment: You have to capture the output as an Azure Pipelines variable. Look elsewhere on the site or in the documentation because variations of this question have been asked here literally hundreds of times.

Comment: I still would like some help with implementing this so if anyone can help it would be great

Comment: Step 1: Figure out how to get Terraform output variables from the CLI. Step 2: Figure out how to set an Azure Pipelines output variable. You've solved Step 2. Now figure out Step 1. Your search engine of choice can help.

Comment: Thats what i need help with..Rather than being cryptic with your replys it would be great if you offered help

Comment: I'm encouraging you to do independent research and show effort in your questions. There's a line between *helping* and *doing it for you*. Did you try searching around for a phrase like "terraform cli get outputs"?

Comment: I am putting in a lot of effort into this but i am searching and learning while doing..this is new to me. I found  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/output but im not sure how to use those cmds.. terraform output -json instance_ips | jq -r '.[0]' or terraform output -raw lb_address

Comment: Great! You've found something that looks like it will help you. Now experiment with the command, look up anything you don't understand, and see if you can figure it out. Read the documentation and experiment, don't just blindly copy and paste commands. For example, if you don't understand what `jq` is, *look it up*. If you're not using a platform that supports `jq`, then look into what alternatives are available on the platform you *are* using. Independent research and experimentation are a critical part of being successful in our field.

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I believe the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) may be of some use to you. You can use `task.setvariable` to assign variables during pipeline execution, which can be accessed in later steps, jobs, or stages, [depending on how which level you choose](https://task.setvariable).

Comment: I have updated the original question with an update pipeline using the info i have found here. But it seems not to be qorking and im not sure if its setup correctly